I am getting a unhashable type: 'set' error when trying to parse a xsd file
I already tried to equal the imported_schema_uris={} but that gives just another mutable? error.
Also scoured the internet for answers but cant seem to find one that puts me on the way.
PS : I am new to python programming
Here's the code :
from xbrl.taxonomy import parse_taxonomy_url
from xbrl.cache import HttpCache
import os

def parse_taxonomy_from_url(schema_url):
    cache_path = './cache'
    if not os.path.exists(cache_path):
        os.makedirs(cache_path)  # Ensure the cache directory exists
    
    cache = HttpCache(cache_path)  # Create an instance of HttpCache
    imported_schema_uris = set()  # Initialize an empty set for imported schema URIs

    # Debugging information
    print(f"Cache directory: {cache_path}")
    print(f"Schema URL: {schema_url}")
    print(f"Imported Schema URIs: {imported_schema_uris}")

    # Parse the taxonomy schema from the given URL
    try:
        taxonomy_schema = parse_taxonomy_url(schema_url=schema_url, cache=cache, imported_schema_uris=imported_schema_uris)
        return taxonomy_schema
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return None

# Example usage 
schema_url = 'http://test.xsd'  
# Replace with a valid URL
parsed_schema = parse_taxonomy_from_url(schema_url)

if parsed_schema:
    print("Taxonomy schema parsed successfully!")
else:
    print("Failed to parse taxonomy schema.")


Hey, without a valid example URL this is kinda hard to reproduce. Could you add a toy link from NCBI or something similar?

"unhashable type: 'set'" -> what is most likely happening is that the code at some point tries to use a variable of type set as a key in a dictionary or set somewhere in the code. Can you find out if that set is something you defined? maybe "imported_schema_uris"?

So I assume you are talking about this function? https://py-xbrl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/taxonomy.html#xbrl.taxonomy.parse_taxonomy_url Then your usage of the last arguments seems correct

Does this happen on every object you try to download? It could be that the one you are using is malformed in someway, or hitting a bug in the parse-function

Because the problem is either with the .xsd you are trying to access, or the logic inside parse_taxonomy_url. I don't see how your program could contain the culprit because you only throw very generic arguments at the function that fails.

Also, do yourself a favor and just don't catch the exception. You are writing lines of code to hide a more precise error-message that could help you. Use the stacktrace for debugging, thats what its there for!
